# Ubuntu 16.04 "sudo apt-get update" error

Tags: 16.04, apt

When I give `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt install -f` I am getting errors and stuck. Below are console logs for your reference.

Logs of `sudo apt-get update` command:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable
InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial     
InRelease                                                                         
Hit:3 http://package.perforce.com/apt/ubuntu trusty     InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable     InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial     
InRelease                                                                   
Hit:6 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable     InRelease                                                                                        
Hit:7 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview     InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                    
Hit:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease                                                                           
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu xenial 
InRelease                                                                    
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa/ubuntu 
xenial InRelease                                                             
0% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::14)] 
[Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::21)]     
[Connecting to o
```

Here my console stuck after this line appeared on the terminal.

Logs of `sudo apt install -f` command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpng12-0:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpng12-0:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.    
Need to get 0 B/122 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 321705 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:i386 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) over (1.2.50-2+deb8u3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/ANNOUNCE', which is different from other instances of package libpng12-0:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me so that I can solve these errors.

Thanks

Comment: Have you made any changes to your Python setup?

Comment: @wjandrea, no i don't made any changes to my Python setup.

Comment: Try clearing the apt cache with `sudo apt-get clean` and even if that fails, try reinstalling `python-minimal` with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal`.